# How do I solve "Can not find symbol" error?

Tags: java

http://pastey.net/143355-1qoa is my code for my java application so far. Each class I am writing has that file with the respective changes (below).

When I try to compile the code, I get the "cannot find symbol" error for each of my 6 classes.How should I go about fixing this?

I am attempting to compile with the following command:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin>javac C:\Divelog\DiveLog.java`

Please keep in mind that I am a complete noob with java programming. If there is an amazing source to learn java, please tell me of it if you can.

Thanks in advance.

```
package divelog;
/**
* This class creates the content on the
* Welcome tabbed pane in the Dive Log
* application.
* @version 1.0
*/
//import for buttons, labels, and images
import javax.swing.*; 
//import for layout manager
import java.awt.*; 

public class Resources extends JPanel
{ //Opens class 


}//Closes class
```

Edit:
Error Message:
C:\Divelog\DiveLog.java:62: connot find symbol
symbol  : class Welcome
location: class divelog.DiveLog
                               new Welcome (),

C:\Divelog\DiveLog.java:68: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Diver
location: class divelog.DiveLog
                               new Diver (),

C:\Divelog\DiveLog.java:73: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Dives
location: class divelog.DiveLog
                               new Dives (),

C:\Divelog\DiveLog.java:78: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Statistics
location: class divelog.DiveLog
                               new Statistics (),

C:\Divelog\DiveLog.java:83: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class WebSite
location: class divelog.DiveLog
                               new WebSite (),

C:\Divelog\DiveLog.java:87: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Resources
location: class divelog.DiveLog
                               new Resources (),

6 errors

Comment: Can you post your error message as well?

Comment: Btw, you can find some tutorials here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167179/java-tutorial

Comment: The full error message or at least the line number would be a great hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should be running javac.exe from the project root.  Never run it from the directory where you installed Java.

Try adding `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin` to your Windows PATH.  [Here's](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) how to do it.  Create a new command shell after you do it and type "set PATH" to verify that the new path has been added.

Navigate to c:\Divelog and create a directory named `classes`.

After you've done that, try compiling like this:

```
C:\Divelog javac -cp .;.\classes -d classes *.java
```

Run your code like this:

```
C:\Divelog java -cp .;.\classes divelog.DiveLog
```

Lose those awful comments - they're the worst.

```
{ //Opens class 


}//Closes class
```

Comment: No, javac will create the package and add it as a subdirectory to /classes.  Try it and see.

Comment: This works, thanks. As long as my applications don't have any errors, this should work in most cases, correct?

Comment: You're most welcome.  Yes, it should work for simple cases like these.  Best to learn more about it, though.

Answer (score 0):

`javac -cp C:\ divelog\DiveLog.java`

It would be better to add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_22\bin>javac` to your PATH environment variable (if it is not there) and compile from your project directory (and keep the project inside a directory and not at the root dir). Also, specify output directory for `javac` to put class files (`-d`).

Comment: If you mean 2 minutes gap, it is because of my internet connection. I see new answers after posting :-/